# How to launch the Ubuntu installer?

Tags: system-installation

To reinstall the system, how would I launch the Ubuntu installer? I could perhaps use the command line? I cannot figure out how to use this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: Boot a live session. The installer will be in your desktop.

Comment: Make a live drive from an Ubuntu iso file into a USB pendrive or DVD disk. Boot from that drive ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the installation media, DVD or USB stick, to do a fresh reinstall.